# How can make facebook friend request box showing in canvas page?

Tags: facebook, request, friend

I want to make an application which appear friends of the user in canvas and then user choose his friends whose want to send request for this app.

I know how to do it with popup window, but i want to do it without it. That I want to do is to show the friend request box in the canvas page

Is these any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used to be able to do it with FBML but this functionality is being / has been removed.

You can create your own friend selector if you have permission to read the logged in user's friend list, and then use the request dialogue, and then use the requests dialog to send requests to the selected users with something like this:

```
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: INVITE_MESSAGE
    to: FACEBOOK_USER_ID_ARRAY
  }, callback);
```

Comment: It's a pleasure, if I answered your question please mark my answer as correct.